# Set system level default screen orientation for an android device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-orientation, root-access

I have a project requirement to create a kiosk based application which will always be in the landscape mode,for which I am making use of a tablet running on 4.2.2.One of the modules has the functionality to make phone calls.For making the calls from my app, I invoke the default android dialer app.However,I notice that even if my device is physically in the landscape mode,at times when the default dialer app is called,it first displays its portrait layout and the quickly switches to the landscape one(which is not visually appealing).Now,since I do not have access to modify the source code of the default dialer app,I was wondering if there is a way that I can specify a system level screen orientation as landscape ?

PS: I have root access for my tablet.
Any help would be appreciated.Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There's an app for that: [Rotation Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devasque.rotationlocker&hl=en)

You can also add the switch `ro.sf.hwrotation 90` in your `build.prop` file